# Why need to add ID field to products categories of of online shopping database?

Tags: sql, database

I am just started to learn about relational database. When I studied the database of online shopping websites, I found that many examples create a category table and added ID field to the category name. I don't know why they need to create a category table and use category ID as a foreign key to relate products table. What will happen if I remove the category table and add the category name directly to the products table?

[image]

Comment: See [Third normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form)

Comment: What will happen is it's much more difficult to change the name of a category because you have to do it in lots of rows instead of one. It's harder to get a unique list of all categories (e.g. to put in a drop-down menu) or to ensure that users always enter a valid category when adding a product (you can't check the ID to see if it exists in the list...so you don't know if it's a mistake or they just want to create a new category). Same if you didn't have unique lists of products or users to associate with each order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I think is a lot of cases that you want a website menu showing your categories. This menu allows people to view your categories (Men Clothing, Women Clothing, Kids, Accessories) and once they click it they can see the products relevant to them.

If you put the category name to the product, it is very hard for you to update your menu content as you need to loop, group the category in the product table. Also, it is harder to update the category name in product table as a category name could be in lots of product records,

Whereas if you have a category table, you just need to maintain the category table (view what you have in the category table and update DB record if you want your menu change).

In long term maintenance, category table is desired.

In a case I have come over that I would like an empty category which just to show in the website menu (a menu item which contains no product) which is not possible if I do not have a category table.

Answer (score 1):

By inserting just the category name you may complete your POC but you need to understand what is Normalization and why it is needed.

**First normal form (1NF)** : An entity type is in 1NF when it contains ***no repeating groups of data***.

**Second normal form (2NF)** : An entity type is in 2NF when it is in 1NF and ***when all of its non-key attributes are fully dependent on its primary key.***

**Third normal form (3NF)** : An entity type is in 3NF when it is in 2NF and ***when all of its attributes are directly dependent on the primary key.***

[Source](http://agiledata.org/essays/dataNormalization.html)

Answer (score 1):

> What will happen if I remove the category table and add the category name directly to the products table?

Suppose you store the category with each product, and one day your boss tells you that you misspelled a category name. Which one?

"Theater" he says. Or did he say "theatre?" Which is correct? You check and find about "theater" and "theatre" are used close to evenly among the products that have either one.

So which spelling did your boss mean is the mistake, and which one is correct?

If you store the correct spelling in one place, in its own categories table, then you can be sure. You can correct it, and all the products that reference it will implicitly get the correction.

That's an argument for normalization, but keep in mind using an integer id is only a convention. It has nothing to do with normalization. You can use a string as a primary key of a table, and therefore you can use a string as a foreign key in a table that references it.

It's okay to use a non-integer for key columns. As long as there is one instance that stores the canonical value, it satisfies the goal of normalization -- that is to reduce *data anomalies*.